# Print values from row if value is not empty PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, is-empty

I'm trying to loop through a table, and only print the values from the row if a certain value is not empty.

```
+------------------+
| value_1 | value_2|
+------------------+
| Tim     |   56   |
+---------+--------+
| Jack    |        |
+---------+--------+
| Sam     |   33   |
+---------+--------+
```

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value_1, value_2 FROM database");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    if (!empty($row[value_2])){
        printf("First Value: %s  Second Value: %s", $row[value_1], $row[value_2] )or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());  
    }

}
```

So in this instance, I would be wanting to out put just the data for Tim and Jack.

If I remove the `!` from the if statement, to make it print out all data where it is empty, this seems to work, however once Itry and switch it and add the `!` nothing is outputted.

Comment: Can you write an else condition and check first?

Comment: @aksappy The if statement is definitely running (using the answer from mfisher91  ) as it is outputting the correct number of 'First Value' 'Second Value' titles

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your query.

```
SELECT value_1, value_2 FROM database WHERE value_2 != ''
```

For the code you've provided, this would be a much simpler option as you have to do less work in PHP (you can just print out the value).

Edit - fixed error mentioned in comment below.

Change the printf line to this:

```
printf("First Value: %s  Second Value: %s", $row['value_1'], $row['value_2'] )or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

You were missing the quotes around the database values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be doing the trick, however the actual values are not outputted, just the first bit of the printf statement, is there an error on that line I am missing?

Comment: Try removing the 'or die' part and see what happens.

Comment: You were missing the quotes around the database values. I've updated my post

Comment: Added these - still no joy

Comment: Try and echo out the two values outside of the printf function (comment the printf function out for now). See if your results are displayed.

Comment: Nope - nothing, doesn't output anything

Answer (score 0):

Changed $row to integer indexes of the array 
`$row['value_1']` > `$row[0]` 
Not the best of fixes but it does the job for now